# Web Scraping using JavaScript from R functions code that is working perfectly

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, r

I'm working with financial data and I want to make a website with HTML (CSS and Javascript) which will scrape data from other sites, put the data in table and plots graphs from data collected.
I've scraped those websites before with some R functions I created, but the problem I'm facing is that I can't directly add my R script to my website.

- I want to use javascript in order to accomplish that. Which is the best way to do it?
- How can i use **R** extension in **visual studio Code** to add the **R function** in my HTML script?

Below is a minimal example of a **R function** that is **working perfectly** (from one of my post [Scrape table with rvest by clicking on button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72077107/scrape-table-with-rvest-by-clicking-on-button) ).

```
library(lubridate)
library(rlang)
library(httr2)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

BRVM_get <- function(ticker ='BICC',
                             Period = 0,
                             from = Sys.Date() - 89,
                             to = Sys.Date() ) {

  first_date <- lubridate::parse_date_time(from, orders = "ymd")
  end_date   <- lubridate::parse_date_time(to, orders = "ymd")

  if (first_date >= end_date){
    rlang::abort(
      "The '.from' parameter (start_date) must be less than '.to' (end_date)"
    )
  }

  else if (first_date >= Sys.Date()-2){
    rlang::abort(
      "The '.from' parameter (start_date) must be less than today's date"
    )
  }

  ticker <- unique(toupper(ticker))
  all_tickers <- c( "ABJC", "BICC", "BNBC", "BOAB", "BOABF", "BOAC",
                "BOAM", "BOAN", "BOAS", "CABC", "CBIBF", "CFAC",
                "CIEC", "ECOC", "ETIT", "FTSC", "NEIC", "NSBC",
                "NTLC", "ONTBF", "ORGT", "PALC", "PRSC", "SAFC",
                "SCRC", "SDCC", "SDSC", "SEMC", "SGBC", "SHEC",
                "SIBC", "SICC", "SIVC", "SLBC", "SMBC", "SNTS",
                "SOGC", "SPHC", "STAC", "STBC", "SVOC", "TTLC",
                "TTLS", "UNLC", "UNXC"
                #, "TTRC"
  )

  # idx <- c("BRVM10","BRVMAG", "BRVMC","BRVMAS",
  #          "BRVMDI", "BRVMFI", "BRVMIN", "BRVMSP", "BRVMTR")

  all_indexes <- c("BRVM10", "BRVMAG", "BRVMC", "BRVMAS", "BRVMDI",
                "BRVMFI", "BRVMIN", "BRVMSP", "BRVMTR")

  ifelse(ticker =="ALL",
         ticker <- all_tickers,
         ticker)

  ifelse(ticker =="ALL INDEXES",
         ticker <- all_indexes,
         ticker)

  .indexes<-list("BRVM 10" = c("BRVM10"),
                 AGRICULTURE = c("BRVMAG"),
                 "BRVM COMPOSITE" =c("BRVMC"),
                 "OTHER SECTOR" = c("BRVMAS"),
                 DISTRIBUTION = c("BRVMDI"),
                 FINANCE = c("BRVMFI"),
                 INDUSTRY = c("BRVMIN"),
                 "PUBLIC SERVICES" = c("BRVMSP"),
                 TRANSPORT = c("BRVMTR"))

  tick_vec <- NULL
  ## Filter ticker in .indexes or all_ticker list

  for (tick in ticker) {
    if (tick %in% .indexes) {
      tick_vec <- c(tick_vec, tick)
    } else if (tick %in% all_tickers){
      if (company_country(tick) == "BENIN") {
        adn <- paste0(tick,".bj")
      } else if (company_country(tick) == "BURKINA FASO") {
        adn <- paste0(tick,".bf")
      } else if (company_country(tick) == "IVORY COAST") {
        adn <- paste0(tick,".ci")
      } else if (company_country(tick) == "MALI") {
        adn <- paste0(tick,".ml")
      } else if (company_country(tick) == "NIGER") {
        adn <- paste0(tick,".ne")
      } else if (company_country(tick) == "SENEGAL") {
        adn <- paste0(tick,".sn")
      } else if (company_country(tick) == "TOGO") {
        adn <- paste0(tick,".tg")
      }
      tick_vec <- c(tick_vec, adn)

    }
  }

  # Check input parameters after filtering ----
  if (length(tick_vec) < 1){
    rlang::abort(
      "The 'ticker' parameter cannot be blank. Please enter at least one ticker.
            If entering multiple please use .symbol = c(Tick_1, Tick_2, ...)"
    )
  } else {
    ticker <- tick_vec
  }

  index_stock <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = 6, nrow = 0))
  names(index_stock) <- c("Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Ticker")

  tryCatch(
    {
      if (as.numeric(Period) %in% c(1, 30, 91, 365) ){
        for (Tick in ticker) {
          ifelse(nchar(Tick) == 7,
                 Tick1 <- str_sub(Tick, 1,4),
                 Tick1 <- Tick)

          my_data <- request("https://www.sikafinance.com/api/general/GetHistos") %>%
            req_body_json(list('ticker'= Tick,
                               'xperiod'= paste0(Period,''))) %>%
            req_perform() %>%
            resp_body_json(simplifyVector = T)

          my_data <- dplyr::as_tibble(my_data$lst)
          my_data$Date<-as.Date.character(my_data$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
          my_data <- my_data[,-6]
          assign(Tick1, my_data, envir = globalenv())

          my_data$Ticker <- Tick1

          index_stock <- rbind(index_stock, my_data)

        }

        if (length(unique(index_stock$Ticker)) > 1) {
          return(index_stock)
        } else {
          return(index_stock[, -6])
        }

      }

      else if (as.numeric(Period) %in% c(0, 5) ){

        for (Tick in ticker) {
          ifelse(nchar(Tick) == 7,
                 Tick1 <- str_sub(Tick, 1,4),
                 Tick1 <- Tick)

          stock.data <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = 7, nrow = 0))
          names(stock.data) <- c("Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Ticker")

          for(.date in seq(end_date, first_date, "-3 months")){
            to_date = as.Date.POSIXct(.date)
            from_date = to_date - 89

            my_data <- request("https://www.sikafinance.com/api/general/GetHistos") %>%
              req_body_json(list('ticker'= Tick,
                                 'datedeb'= from_date,
                                 'datefin'= to_date,
                                 'xperiod'= paste0(Period,''))) %>%
              req_perform() %>%
              resp_body_json(simplifyVector = T)

            if (length(my_data$lst)==6) {
              my_data <- dplyr::as_tibble(my_data$lst)
              stock.data <- rbind(stock.data, my_data)
            }

          }

          if (length(stock.data)==6 && nrow(stock.data)!=0) {

            stock.data$Date<-as.Date.character(stock.data$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")

            ifelse (any(duplicated(stock.data$Date)),
                    stock.data<-stock.data%>%
                      dplyr::group_by(Date)%>%
                      summarise(Open=mean(Open),
                                High= mean(High),
                                Low= mean(Low),
                                Close= mean(Close)),
                    stock.data)

            print(paste0("We obtained ",Tick1,  " data from ",
                         min(stock.data$Date),
                         " to ",
                         max(stock.data$Date)))

            assign(Tick1, stock.data, envir = globalenv())
            stock.data$Ticker <- Tick1

            index_stock <- rbind(index_stock, stock.data )

          } else {
            print(paste0(Tick1," data aren't available between ",
                         first_date,
                         " and ",
                         end_date))
          }

        }

        if (length(unique(index_stock$Ticker)) > 1) {
          return(index_stock)
        } else {
          return(index_stock[, -6])
        }

      }

      else {
        print("Choose the best period between 0, 1, 5, 30, 91 and 365")
      }

    },
    error = function(e) {
      print("Make sure you have an active internet connection")
    },
    warning = function(w) {
      print("Make sure you have an active internet connection")
    }
  )

}

#Example

BRVM_get("Bicc", Period = 91 ) # To get quaterly data
head(BICC)
# <date>     <int> <int> <int> <int>  <int>
#  2022-05-17  6000  6000  5550  5550    498
#  2022-05-18  5560  5560  5560  5560     10
#  2022-05-19  5975  5975  5975  5975      1
#  2022-05-20  6000  6000  6000  6000    500
#  2022-05-23  5600  6200  5600  6200    213
#  2022-05-24  5600  6200  5600  6200    213
```

Is there a way to scrape data directely from that [website](https://www.sikafinance.com/marches/historiques?s=SIVC.ci) to my website? Or How Can i turn my R script (R function) in javascript code to integrate it in my web script/ iframe.
Further response will be appreciate (CSS or PHP in case i'm not finding any issue for javascript)

The data i want to scrape should have the same behaviour as the picture one for each ticker selected.
[image: data i want to scrape with javascript in HTML].

After clicking on **DONNEES** which you can see on my website draft below [image: the draft of my siteweb] I want the data i'll scrape to have the same component ie user will be abble to select **Ticker**, **Time Period**, **From**, **To** and then click Button **OK** to see data.

Comment: If your goal is a one-time scrape, you may be able to make your function into an `htmlwidget` ([read more about that here](https://book.javascript-for-r.com/widgets-first.html)). For reiterative use with an iframe. you could potentially use Replit ([read about that here](https://replit.com/)) or Rdrr ([read about that here](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embedding/)). You may be able to use a Shiny backend, too. (I don't know anything about your site to say for sure.) Once you decide on a route, I think I can help you institute one or many of these ideas.

Comment: Thanks for those differents issues you gave. I'm new in javascript but I master R more. How Can WE keep in touch to help me Institute one or many of your ideas?

Comment: There's really no safe way to share information in SO. If you mean in terms of coding questions, others have asked the question to SO as a whole, then left a comment on a question I answered or in response to a comment I made with a link to that question. Another option may be to open something up on Github. You can leave a link to the site the same way.

Comment: It sounds good. Let me some minutes to write the issue in github and add the link hère. Thanks again.